# Azure Appservice easy auth proxy from Azure Front Foor stripping pathing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I am working on a solution where I want to have multiple apps routed by the front door in the following schema using only managed SSL certificates.

```
<company1>.<basedomain>         =>  app 0  
<company1>.<basedomain>/app1    =>  app 1  
<company1>.<basedomain>/app2    =>  app 2  
<company2>.<basedomain>         =>  app 3  
<company2>.<basedomain>/app4    =>  app 4  
<company2>.<basedomain>/app5    =>  app 5
```

These domains are all configured as CNames pointing to app services, and all of these apps are using easy auth.
I have been following this tutorial (Deploying a secure, resilient site with a custom domain - Azure App Service) to proxy the call through the app service to AD auth to redirect back to the front door.

I am having an issue when the app service redirects to AD, replacing pathing with /.auth/login/add/callback.  When the redirect happens, even though we started at app 1, we are redirected to app 0.
I have tried ensuring the redirect and audience contain the path on the app service, and also, the redirect on the app registration includes the path. Still, regardless this pathing is always stripped, and then you get the expected:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to maintain the pathing on the redirect from AppService to AD?

Comment: How about using only one webapp (windows platform), and you can deploy your other  5 webapps in  it's virtual application. Hope this  can help you, if you need further help, you can let me know.

Comment: @JasonPan   Thanks for the input.  It is hard to capture the entire context of the problem while trying to be concise, but this framework will be used for many web globally distributed web apps that require independent horizontally scalability and high availability.   Given those requirements, your proposed solution would fall short.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have CNAMES pointing to app services if you use front door, well you can but you don't want to, the CNAME should be pointing to your front door and it will forward the request to the proper backend and if you have configured your AD App Registration correctly it will work perfectly.